# EnvironmentObject not injected for .navigationDestination

Tags: swift, swiftui

Consider code

```
@EnvironmentObject var navModel: NavigationModel
var body: some View {
    someView
       .navigationDestination(for: ImageModel.self) { imageModel in
                ImageDetailedView(image: imageModel)
                    .environmentObject(navModel)   //this is required 
       }
}
```

Is navigation not considered a child of the view? And if so, is it normal to keep throwing around environemntObjects around the navigation stack?

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

enum Destination {
    case firstPage
    case secondPage
}

enum Category: Int, Hashable, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case dessert
    case pancake
    case salad
    case sandwich
    
    var id: Int { rawValue }
    
    var localizedName: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
        case .dessert:
            return "Dessert"
        case .pancake:
            return "Pancake"
        case .salad:
            return "Salad"
        case .sandwich:
            return "Sandwich"
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
class Coordinator3: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func gotoHomePage() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
    
    func tapOnEnter() {
        path.append(Destination.firstPage)
    }
    
    func tapOnFirstPage() {
        path.append(Destination.secondPage)
    }
    
    func tapOnSecondPage() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func test() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
        path.append(2)
    }
}

class Test :ObservableObject {
    var name = "test"
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SplitTestView: View {
    @State var selectedCategory: Category?
    var categories = Category.allCases
    @ObservedObject var coordinator = Coordinator3()
    @StateObject var test = Test()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(categories, selection: $selectedCategory) { category in
                NavigationLink(category.localizedName, value: category)
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
                switch selectedCategory {
                case .dessert:
                    Text(selectedCategory!.localizedName)
                case .pancake:
                    VStack {
                        Text("Navigation stack")
                            .padding()
                        NavigationLink("NavigationLink to enter first page", value: Destination.firstPage)
                            .padding()
                        NavigationLink("NavigationLink to enter second page", value: Destination.secondPage)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                        if destination == .firstPage {
                            FirstPage()
                        } else {
                            Text(
                                "SecondPage()"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                case .salad: Text(selectedCategory!.localizedName)
                case .sandwich: Text(selectedCategory!.localizedName)
                case .none: Text("hi")
                }
            }.environmentObject(test)
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SplitTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SplitTestView()
    }
}
struct FirstPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var test: Test
    var body: some View {
        Text("First Page \(test.name)")
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven’t provided a reproducible example but more than likely 1. You didn’t inject on the stack, not within it has to be on, 2. You haven’t  injected in the view before this screen 3. The source of truth isn’t a StateObject.

Comment: @loremipsum nope apparently it's a known problem for at least 2 years. Injection does not work across Navigation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59812640/environmentobject-doesnt-work-well-through-navigationlink

Comment: @loremipsum stop giving out incorrect answers if you dont know the subject. You've been flagged. The answer is clearly stated by Apple here https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683564

Comment: `NavigationStack{/*other stuff that includes a navigationDestination*/}.environmentObject(navModel)` will 100% work if you have `@StateObject var navModel: NavigationModel = NavigationModel()` in the same `View` with the Stack. I have no doubt about this. Notice that the injection is **on** the closing bracket. You can report all you want, Apple did not confirm this is a bug in that link.

Comment: @loremipsum sorry it just doesn't post a project that shows it otherwise

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is why MREs are important that is why I mentioned it in my first comment, you introduced `NavigationSplitView`.

*Scenario 1*

If you are using `NavigationSplitView` you have to inject the `EnvironmentObject` to the `NavigationSplitView`.

```
NavigationSplitView{
    /*other stuff that includes a navigationDestination*/
}.environmentObject(navModel)
```

*Scenerio 2*

When working with just `NavigationStack` you have to inject on the `NavigationStack`

```
NavigationStack{
    /*other stuff that includes a navigationDestination*/
}.environmentObject(navModel)
```

*Scenerio 3* ***- Deprecated***

When working with just `NavigationView` you have to inject on the `NavigationView`

```
NavigationView{
    /*other stuff that includes a NavigationLink*/
}.environmentObject(navModel)
```

*Your Sample*

Just move the injection code one line down.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SplitTestView: View {
    @State var selectedCategory: Category?
    var categories = Category.allCases
    @StateObject var coordinator = Coordinator3() //<-- Switch to StateObject
    @StateObject var test = Test()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(categories, selection: $selectedCategory) { category in
                NavigationLink(category.localizedName, value: category)
            }
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack(path: $coordinator.path) {
                switch selectedCategory {
                case .dessert:
                    Text(selectedCategory!.localizedName)
                case .pancake:
                    VStack {
                        Text("Navigation stack")
                            .padding()
                        NavigationLink("NavigationLink to enter first page", value: Destination.firstPage)
                            .padding()
                        NavigationLink("NavigationLink to enter second page", value: Destination.secondPage)
                            .padding()
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: Destination.self) { destination in
                        if destination == .firstPage {
                            FirstPage()
                        } else {
                            Text(
                                "SecondPage()"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                case .salad: Text(selectedCategory!.localizedName)
                case .sandwich: Text(selectedCategory!.localizedName)
                case .none: Text("hi")
                }
            }
        }.environmentObject(test) //<<--- Add to the NavigationSplitView - The NavigationLink's are presenting in a separate column than the Stack, the only thing they share is the split view.
    }
}
enum Destination {
    case firstPage
    case secondPage
}

enum Category: Int, Hashable, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Codable {
    case dessert
    case pancake
    case salad
    case sandwich
    
    var id: Int { rawValue }
    
    var localizedName: LocalizedStringKey {
        switch self {
        case .dessert:
            return "Dessert"
        case .pancake:
            return "Pancake"
        case .salad:
            return "Salad"
        case .sandwich:
            return "Sandwich"
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 16.0, *)
class Coordinator3: ObservableObject {
    @Published var path = NavigationPath()
    
    func gotoHomePage() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
    }
    
    func tapOnEnter() {
        path.append(Destination.firstPage)
    }
    
    func tapOnFirstPage() {
        path.append(Destination.secondPage)
    }
    
    func tapOnSecondPage() {
        path.removeLast()
    }
    
    func test() {
        path.removeLast(path.count)
        path.append(2)
    }
}

class Test :ObservableObject {
    var name = "test"
}



@available(iOS 16.0, *)
struct SplitTestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SplitTestView()
    }
}
struct FirstPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var test: Test
    var body: some View {
        Text("First Page \(test.name)")
    }
}
```

*Addl Info*

In the Migration Guide apple talks about the differences between the 2 types.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-to-new-navigation-types

They call the inside of the `NavigationStack` "content"

```
NavigationStack {
    /* content */
}
```

And the inside of the `NavigationSplitView` "columns"

```
NavigationSplitView {
    /* column 1 */
} content: {
    /* column 2 */
} detail: {
    /* column 3 */
}
```

In their respective setups the "columns" and "content" only share the `NavigationSplitView` or `NavigationStack` respectively with the `NavigationLink`s/`navigationDestination`.

A `NavigationLink` inside `NavigationStack` that is inside `NavigationSplitView` presents in its own column.

**The injection should always happen at the uppermost shared `View`.**

Comment: Ok you are correct, I have accepted the answer. But I still don't understand why injecting it at the NavigationStack level fails, but for some reason, a level above NavigationSplitView would work. The idea is that you inject it so that all subviews would have access. So A->B->C. If you inject at A it works, but if you inject at B it fails? Weird.

Comment: @erotsppa according to your link that is “Apple’s design”. I look at it like B and C are eggs in a carton. A is the carton. The eggs are connected via the carton. They can’t share with each other but the carton can. Idk maybe it’s a silly analogy.

Comment: But that's not the case here. Let's explore the tree. A (NavigationSplitView), B (NavigationStack), C1 (VStack), C2 (view inserted by navigationDestination). Ok so we know that C2 crashes, if you inject at B. But it works if you inject at A. According to documentation, all subviews will have access to inserted EO. So that MUST mean that C1 and C2 are not subviews of NavigationStack, but instead somehow subviews of NavigationSplitView. Ok I can understand that maybe NavigationStack was not never part of the hierarchy since it's a "column", then how does it become a child view of A?

Comment: @erotsppa only Apple can answer that. Maybe submit a feedback

Comment: @loremipsum I'm using this approach which works well with me except for the case in which I need to pass an environmentObject in (for ex.) `FirstPage` view, so in the `.navigationDestination` closure above I can't pass an environmentObject (I'm not talking about passing test object which's defined in the root level view), I'm trying to inject an object into `FirstPage` which comes from another view (for ex.) `SomeOtherView`, in this case the environment object can't be defined in the top root view and is defined only in `SomeOtherView`

Comment: Don’t use EnvironmentObject use ObservedObject and do something similar to what I did with the path. You’ll just have to make the Object conform to Hashable. EnvironmentObject should start at the root. @JAHelia

Comment: @loremipsum that makes sense, will try to convert it to `ObservedObject` and pass it through the init, thank you so much for the suggested solution

Comment: @loremipsum conforming a complex ObservableObject to Hashable is a mess for my case, because it includes many sub-objects, so I have to walkthrough each object of those and make them conform to Hashable. I couldn't find a better way to pass such complex ObservableObject in the `.navigationDestination` closure :(

Comment: @JAHelia you don’t need anything complex just use an id, see if it works. But a large Object with several other Objects is quite inefficient you would be completely invalidating views instead of targeted  redrawing. If you look at Apple documents you’ll notice that ObservableObjects are meant to be used as simple Data Models. I am a big fan of Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that as my projects get more complex, using EnvironmentObjects get a bit buggy. Something I've been incorperating is shared singleton classes instead of EnvironmentObjects classes.

To do this, inside of your class, list a property `static let shared = NavigationModel()`. Then, in any view you want to use that class, reference it in the view properties as `@ObservedObject var  navModel = NavigationModel.shared`.

There are pros and cons to this approach, but I've found that the pros outweigh the cons as environment objects tend to be buggy.

Comment: I tend to agree. Unless anyone else have found any downside. I'm not even sure why they invented environmentObject

Comment: This is a workaround that demonstrates a misunderstanding of how EnvironmentObject works. For it to pass to subviews such as NavigationLinks you have to inject **on** the stack.

Comment: @loremipsum please provide a minimum working example demonstrating this

Comment: @erotsppa you already have the answer, you can add it to the marked answer if you want to. You didn’t provide an MRE to start all of this would have been over with a long time ago if you provided an MRE

Comment: @loremipsum just to proof you wrong, here you go MRE https://github.com/dpyy/TestInjection.git

Comment: look at the answer I posted

Comment: @loremipsum I understand you need to inject the env obj on the stack, I was just saying I've had legitamite SwiftUI bugs working with them in the past

Comment: @loremipsum whats the advantage of using environmentObject over just a global?

Comment: @erotsppa global as in this solution you lose the ability to change your environment mocks, previews, etc. it is also a preference thing there is a ton of debate on singletons online, I personally try to only use them when dealing with delegates. I like using Dependency Injection.

Answer (score -1):

It is a known behaviour that environmentObjects do not flow through the navigation system. You have to do manual injections every time.

Additionally in the WWDC lounges someone asked:

> I’ve had several intermittent crashes from environment objects being
> nil when I pass them to a sheet or NavigationLink. [...]

The answer was:

> NavigationLink by design doesn’t flow EnvironmentObjects through to
> its destination as it’s unclear where the environmentObject should be
> inherited from. I suspect this might what’s causing your issue. In
> order to get the behavior you expect, you’ll have to explicitly pass
> the environmentObject through at that point.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/683564

Comment: Like the comment says this is not a bug it is design, if you inject in the upper most `View` that is shared such a `NavigationStack`, `NavigationView`, `NavigationSplitView` or `TabVIew`, etc. then all the `NavigationLink`s will have access to the `EnvironmentObject` because it isn't the link sharing the object it is the upper most `View`. MREs important for context.