# Can't access EnvironmentObject from Class

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a @EnvironmentObject AppStateModel that I use in ExampleView, ExampleView uses a class ExampleClass. I need to access a string inside AppStateModel in ExampleClass.

this is the code I'm trying to use:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: AppStateModel
    @ObservedObject var exampleClass: ExampleClass


    var body: some View {
       SomeOtherView(items: exampleClass.items)
    }
}
```

```
class ExampleClass: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items: [...] = []
    
    init() {
    // my code..
}
```

When I tried adding `@EnvironmentObject var model: AppStateModel` to ExampleClass and used model.someString I got this error:

forks.protons.0n@icloud.com
I get Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type AppStateModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for AppStateModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Comment: You only use @EnvironmentObjec inside a view but it's unclear if that is the issue since there seems to be some code missing to really understand this question. Could you point out the line of code that generates the error or include it if it isn't in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EnvironementObject not injected for navigationDestination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752604/environementobject-not-injected-for-navigationdestination)

Comment: if I can't use EnvironmentObject then how can I access the string inside EnvironmentObject from the class?

Comment: Inject it into your class from the View explicitly. `.onAppear { exampleClass.model = ... }`

Comment: `@EnvironmentObject` is for the `View` struct which is where your view data should be transformed. Something is wrong with your SwiftUI code if you are trying to use `@EnvironmentObject` in a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need access to AppStateModel from whole app - you need initialise EnvironmentObject on the start of app:

```
struct YourAppName: App {
@State private var appStateModel = AppStateModel()
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        AppView()
            .environmentObject(appStateModel)
    }
}
```

After it you can access to your AppStateModel using

> @EnvironmentObject var model: AppStateModel

UPD:

You can pass EnvironmentObject from ExampleView to Example class like this:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var model: AppStateModel
@ObservedObject var exampleClass: ExampleClass


var body: some View {
   SomeOtherView(items: exampleClass.items)
        .onAppear {
            self.exampleClass.setModel(model: model)
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes my problem is that I can only use EnvironmentObject in Views, but I need to acces it in a class.

Comment: update answer, try something like this