# Passing result from array into next view

Tags: arrays, firebase, swiftui

I now have a second problem.  I originally passed a value from a list array into another view easily.  Now i am not using a array, how can i pass it now?

viewModel:

```
    class MeetingViewModel: ObservableObject{
        init(){
            Task{ try await fetchAllMeetings() }
            Task{ try await fetchMeeting()}
        }
        
        @Published var upcomingmeeting: Meeting?
        @Published var meetings1 = [Meeting]() {
            didSet {
                if let first = meetings1.first {
                    upcomingmeeting = first
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

"Old" Main View:

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI
struct MeetingSubView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MeetingViewModel()

    var meet: Meeting
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            ForEach(viewModel.meetings1) { meet in
                ZStack {
                    NavigationLink(value: meet) {
                        EmptyView()
                    }.opacity(0.0)
                    
                    MeetingsRowViewDetailed(meeting: meet, viewModel: viewModel)
                        .onAppear {
                            if meet == viewModel.meetings1.last {
                                print("DEBUG: Paginate here..")
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: Meeting.self, destination: { meet in
                MeetingProfileView( meet: meet)
            })
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            Task { try await viewModel.fetchMeeting()}
        })
    }
}
```

"New" Main View: I want to pass this "upcomingmeeting" to second view as "meet" like before.

```
    @StateObject var viewModel = MeetingViewModel()

var body: some view{

       VStack{
             Text(viewModel.upcomingmeeting?.title ?? "no name")
             Text(viewModel.upcomingmeeting?.hostsite ?? "no name")
       }
       .foregroundColor(.white)
       .padding()




}
```

Second View (This needs meet: passed from first view to "MeetingProfileView"). I was able to get it using the list array.

```
struct MeetingProfileView: View  {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MeetingViewModel()

    let meet:Meeting

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            ZStack{
                KFImage(URL(string: meet.profileImageUrl ?? ""))
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: 800, height: 800)
//                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    .opacity(0.5)
                    .grayscale(0.8)
            }
        
            VStack(alignment: .center){
                VStack{
                    Text(meet.title)
                        .font(.title2)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    Text(meet.hostsite)
                    Text(meet.notes)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 100)
                        .padding()
                        .lineLimit(5)
                }
                .padding(.init(top: 50, leading: 100, bottom: 75, trailing: 100))
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.fetchTechMeet(meet)
        }
    }
```

This fixed it:

```
                if let meet = viewModel.upcomingmeeting{
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink(destination: MeetingProfileView(meet: meet)) {
                            
                            InputView3(title: viewModel.upcomingmeeting?.title ?? "", time: viewModel.upcomingmeeting?.hostsite ?? "", room: viewModel.upcomingmeeting?.citystate ?? "")
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `MeetingViewModel()` you create a different instance. One does not know about the other.

You can share an `ObservableObject` using `ObservedObject` or `EnvironmentObject`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app

[EnvironmentObject not injected for .navigationDestination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752604/environmentobject-not-injected-for-navigationdestination)

Comment: Uhm. yeah.  im not sure how to transform "upcomingmeeting" into "meet" after reading all of this.