# Adding EnvironmentObject to view causes error on navigationDestination

Tags: swiftui

I have a simple view with a list that takes the user to another view when they tap a list item:

```
struct SearchView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                List(results, id: \.self) { result in
                    AutocompletePlaceView(
                        vm: vm,
                        result: result
                    )
                    .background(
                        NavigationLink("", value: result.placeID)
                            .opacity(0)
                    )
                }
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self, destination: PlaceView.init)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following error on the `navigationDestination` line:

> Cannot convert value of type '(String, EnvironmentObject) -> PlaceView' to expected argument type '(String) -> PlaceView'

This only started happening after I added an `@EnvironmentObject` to the `PlaceView`:

```
struct PlaceView: View {
    let googlePlaceId: String
    
    @EnvironmentObject var startupViewModel: StartupViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        //
    }
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752604/environmentobject-not-injected-for-navigationdestination/75841146#75841146

Comment: Have you tried this:
 `.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { str in PlaceView(googlePlaceId: str) }`
 and
 `.environmentObject(startupViewModel)` attached to the `NavigationStack`
 assuming you have declared `@StateObject private var startupViewModel = StartupViewModel()` up in your view hierarchy.

Comment: Or use an `@ObservedObject` variable in PlaceView as long as SearchView has an @StateObject variable to go with.