Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type StoryVM found
I’m new to SwiftUI and I’m trying to use Firebase to manage stories in my app. My code works fine when using dummy data, but when I switch to Firebase, I get the following error:
A View.environmentObject(_:) for StoryVM may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Here’s my setup:

View 1: StoryCellView displays a single story.
View 2:
StoryCircleView shows a horizontal scroll of StoryCellView.
View
Model: StoryVM handles fetching stories from Firebase.

Code Overview:
StoryCellView: Displays individual stories.
struct StoryCellView: View {
    @Binding var story: Story
    var isSeen: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StoryVM
    var body: some View {

        Text(story.name ?? "")
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                
                    .frame(minWidth: 62, maxWidth: 62, minHeight: 62, maxHeight: 62)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .padding(2)
                    .background(scheme == .dark ? .black: .gray, in: Circle())
                    .padding(3)
                    .background(
                        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange, .red, .orange]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .opacity(isSeen ? 0 : 1)
                            
                    )
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation{
                            //story.isSeen = true
                            viewModel.markStoryAsSeen(story)
                            viewModel.currentStory = story.id ?? ""
                            viewModel.showStory = true
                            print("Story tapped: \(story.id ?? "")")
                        }
                    }
        
                    

    }
}

StoryCircleView: Displays the scrollable list of stories.
struct StoryCircleView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StoryVM
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 12, content: {
                ForEach($viewModel.stories) { $story in
                    
                    StoryCellView(story: $story) //revert back to original when auth is implemented
                        .environmentObject(viewModel)
                    
    
                }
                
            })
            .padding()
            .padding(.top, 10)
        }
        
        
        .onAppear{
            //viewModel.getStoriesCount()
            viewModel.getStories()
        }
    }
}

View Model (StoryVM): Handles fetching and managing stories.
@MainActor
final class StoryVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showStory: Bool =  false
    
    @Published var currentStory: String = ""
    
    @Published var stories: [Story] = []
    
    private var isSeenStatus: [String: Bool] = [:]
    
    private var lastDocument: DocumentSnapshot? = nil
//    func getAllProducts() async throws {
//        self.products = try await ProductsManager.shared.getAllProducts()
//
//    }
    
    func getStories(){
        Task{
            do{
                let (newStories, lastDocument) = try await StoriesManager.shared.getAllStories(count: 8, lastDocument: lastDocument)
                
                self.stories.append(contentsOf: newStories)
                if let lastDocument {
                    self.lastDocument = lastDocument
                }
                
                newStories.forEach { story in
                                if isSeenStatus[story.id ?? ""] == nil {
                                    isSeenStatus[story.id ?? ""] = false
                                }
                            }
                
                print("you ran me!!!")
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    //will manage seen status when authentication has been implemented
    func markStoryAsSeen(_ story: Story) {
            if let storyID = story.id {
                isSeenStatus[storyID] = true
            }
        }

        func isStorySeen(_ story: Story) -> Bool {
            if let storyID = story.id {
                return isSeenStatus[storyID] ?? false
            }
            return false
        }
    
       func getStoriesCount() {
           Task {
               let count = try await StoriesManager.shared.getAllStoriesCount()
                print("all story count \(count)")
            }
        }
}


ContentView: Top-level view.
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @StateObject private var viewModel = StoryVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{
            let size = $0.size
            let safeArea = $0.safeAreaInsets
            NavigationStack{
                StoryCircleView()
                
                    .overlay(
                        StoryView(size: size, safeArea: safeArea)
                            
                        
                            .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                        
                    )
            }
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}


My Question:
Why does this error occur when using Firebase, and how can I resolve it?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance for your help!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752604/environmentobject-not-injected-for-navigationdestination/75841146#75841146

Where did you declare @StateObject var viewModel = StoryVM() in the parent view,
and did you pass it to the subviews using .environmentObject(viewModel)?
Note, in StoryCircleView you should remove the .environmentObject(viewModel)
or at least move it outside the ScrollView.

@workingdogsupportUkraine the only place I declared (at)StateObject var viewModel = StoryVM() is in the contentView. and moving it outside the scrollview didn't fix it. I tried using (at)StateObject instead of (at)environmentobject it cleared the error. but then the overlay in content view stopped working

@workingdogsupportUkraine any idea why the overlay in the content view stopped working after OP used StateObject

You’re mixing up model data and view data. Only the stories should be in the model class. Selection should be view @state. That way same model can be used in multiple views.

thanks for this explanation @malhal. you guys are the best. I've actually learnt a lot from the comments here

Here is my basic test code that does not crash for me.
Note, an id (eg story.id) should not be Optional.
Also you must have only one source of truth, that is only one @StateObject private var viewModel = StoryVM() in your ContentView(as you have it) that you pass to other views, multiple of such is not acceptable.
// for testing
struct Story: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()  // <--- here, not optional
    var name: String
}


struct StoryCellView: View {
    @Binding var story: Story
    
    var isSeen: Bool = false
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var scheme
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StoryVM
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(story.name)
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .fontWeight(.heavy)
            .frame(minWidth: 62, maxWidth: 62, minHeight: 62, maxHeight: 62)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .padding(2)
            .background(scheme == .dark ? .black: .gray, in: Circle())
            .padding(3)
            .background(
                LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .orange, .red, .orange]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .opacity(isSeen ? 0 : 1)
            )
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation{
                    //story.isSeen = true
                    viewModel.markStoryAsSeen(story)
         //           viewModel.currentStory = story.id ?? ""
                    viewModel.showStory = true
         //           print("Story tapped: \(story.id ?? "")")
                    print("---> in StoryCellView Story tapped: \(story.id)")
                }
            }
    }
}

struct StoryCircleView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StoryVM
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 12, content: {
                ForEach($viewModel.stories) { $story in
                    StoryCellView(story: $story)  // <--- here, no .environmentObject
                }
            })
            .padding()
            .padding(.top, 10)
        }
        .onAppear{
            viewModel.getStoriesCount()
            viewModel.getStories()
            print("----> in StoryCircleView viewModel: \(viewModel.stories.count) ")
        }
    }
}

@MainActor
final class StoryVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showStory: Bool =  false
    
    @Published var currentStory: String = ""
    
    // <--- for testing
    @Published var stories: [Story] = [Story(name: "story-1"), Story(name: "story-2")]
    
    private var isSeenStatus: [String: Bool] = [:]
    
//    private var lastDocument: DocumentSnapshot? = nil
    
    func getStories(){ }
    
    //will manage seen status when authentication has been implemented
    func markStoryAsSeen(_ story: Story) { }
    
    func isStorySeen(_ story: Story) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    func getStoriesCount() { }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @StateObject private var viewModel = StoryVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            let safeArea = $0.safeAreaInsets
            NavigationStack{
                StoryCircleView()
                   .overlay(
                    StoryView(size: size, safeArea: safeArea)
                          .toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar)
                   )
            }
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

// for testing
struct StoryView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StoryVM  // <--- here
    
    let size: CGSize
    let safeArea: EdgeInsets
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("StoryView")
            .onAppear {
                print("----> in StoryView viewModel: \(viewModel.stories.count) ")
            }
    }
}


you sir are a genius.... you deserve a chilled bottle of beer

glad it finally worked for you, happy coding.

thank @workingdogsupportUkraine

have you tried changing the @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: StoryVM to @stateObject var viewModel = StoryVM()

this fixed the error, any idea how to get the overlay in content view to work. from the output in the terminal, I can see that the ontapgesture works, but the overlay isn't working. its strange considering that if I use @environmentObject the overlay works

sincerely i have no idea why your overlay doesn't work. probably some experts will see your question and provide a better insight

You must have only one source of truth, that is only one @StateObject private var viewModel = StoryVM() in your ContentView (as you have it), that you pass to other views, multiple of such is not acceptable. Provided my test code as an answer. Can you also tell us which line of your code gives the error.
