Sharing the same EnvironmentObject between different views in Navigationstack
My Problem is that an instance UserDataProvider is created when entering the firstPage case, because I need the variables traveler, user and cabin. Otherwise I would create one global UserDataProvider.
What I want is that every page after the first gets the exact same UserDataProvider, that is created when entering the case firstPage, but I couldn't figure out how to do that.
@ViewBuilder func view(for route: ManifestRouter.Route) -> some View {
    switch route {
    case let .firstPage(traveler, user, cabin):
        ManifestFirstPage(manifestRouter: manifestRouter, cabin: cabin)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .environmentObject(UserDataProvider(traveler: traveler, user: user))
    case let .secondPage(cabin):
        ManifestSecondPage(manifestRouter: manifestRouter, cabin: cabin)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    case let .thirdPage(cabin):
        ManifestThirdPage(manifestRouter: manifestRouter, cabin: cabin)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}


Welcome. Please don't tag your titles. See [ask]. Also take the [tour].

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75752604/environmentobject-not-injected-for-navigationdestination/75841146#75841146

it's best not to try to use routes and instead embrace SwiftUI by defining multiple .navigationDestination will all kinds of different types containing the data each destination needs.
